# When does Xamarin Forms trigger binding?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a custom control and created a `bindable property`. I wanted to setup the children based on these properties. **What is the correct way** of handling this scenario? I tried looking for anything that makes sense to override in a base control or events that I can hook up.

For example, I want to create the column/row definitions of a `Grid` when I set the `ColumnCount` and `RowCount` in `XAML`

```cs
public class HeatMap: Grid
{
        public HeatMap()
        {
             // Where should I move these?
              Enumerable.Range(1, RowCount)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(x => RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto }));
              Enumerable.Range(1, ColumnCount)
                  .ToList()
                  .ForEach(x => ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }));
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty RowCountProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create<HeatMap, int>(p => p.RowCount, 0);

        public int RowCount
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(RowCountProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RowCountProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ColumnCountProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create<HeatMap, int>(p => p.ColumnCount, 0);

        public int ColumnCount
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnCountProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ColumnCountProperty, value); }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean update columns/rows on when properties are updated?
`BindableProperty.Create` has argument `propertyChanged` to handle value updates.

```cs
public class HeatMap : Grid
{
    public HeatMap()
    {
        // Where should I move these?
        UpdateRows ();
        UpdateColumns ();
    }

    void UpdateColumns ()
    {
        ColumnDefinitions.Clear ();
        Enumerable.Range (1, ColumnCount).ToList ().ForEach (x => ColumnDefinitions.Add (new ColumnDefinition () {
            Width = new GridLength (1, GridUnitType.Star)
        }));
    }

    void UpdateRows ()
    {
        RowDefinitions.Clear ();
        Enumerable.Range (1, RowCount).ToList ().ForEach (x => RowDefinitions.Add (new RowDefinition () {
            Height = GridLength.Auto
        }));
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty RowCountProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<HeatMap, int> (p => p.RowCount, 0,
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => ((HeatMap)bindable).UpdateRows ());

    public int RowCount
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RowCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowCountProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ColumnCountProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<HeatMap, int>(p => p.ColumnCount, 0,
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => ((HeatMap)bindable).UpdateColumns ());

    public int ColumnCount
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnCountProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to setup everything like the positioning, properties, etc. when the control is created and applies the binding values to **all** bindable properties. I don't want it on the property changed of each bindable property because what if you have a scenario where you depend on the `ColumnCount` at the same time when `RowCount` is fired.

Comment: You could override void `OnBindingContextChanged` method in your class but anyway you should handle `propertyChanged` to update your control when bindings are actually changed. If you have two properties used to build element you will have to update element each time when any of these properties is changed (of course in methods like `UpdateRows/UpdateRows` you can use any number of properties).

Comment: Yeah, I was doing OnBindingContextChanged but wasn't sure if there are better ways for handling it. Thanks though :)